# is importing entire module is Ok each time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, class, module

I am working on an angular project and using firebase.
My question is What if I import the entire firebase module in each component Vs importing only what I required in that component from the firebase module?
Why should I not import the entire module each time when I require it ?

Answer (score 0):

This will increase the loading time for your component. It is better to only load the module that your are going to use.
For example import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations'; instead of import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular';